# Is it possible to roll your own syntax sugar (like do-notation, or arrow-notation) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar, do-notation

Well, the question is self-explicative. Suppose I want to implement some special syntax just for fun. Is it possible? What tools should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such meta-syntax in the Haskell standard, but there is in GHC.  You can make almost any notation you want using the GHC "quasi-quotation" facilities (which are different from GHC's "Template Haskell" facility).

The [GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html#th-quasiquotation) on this is quite short, and mainly points to haskell wiki [page on Quasiquotation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation) and the implementor's [home page](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mainland/projects/quasiquoting/), both of these point to the original publication: ["Why It’s Nice to be Quoted: Quasiquoting for Haskell"](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~mainland/publications/mainland07quasiquoting.pdf).

People have used quasi-quotation for embedding XML syntax, regular expressions, special string and text forms, and in "JMacro is a library for the programmatic generation of Javascript code."

Answer (score 8):

I guess, the best way would be to write a custom preprocessor. Several syntactic extensions started out from this approach. For instance, see:

- [DrIFt](http://repetae.net/computer/haskell/DrIFT/): Automatized generation of type class instances
- [arrowp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp): Preprocessor for arrow notation
- [c2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs-0.15.0): Automated generation of marshalling informations and type-signatures for FFI-bindings

and many more. The other way is to patch GHC, but this approach is rather difficult.